# Validate that belongs_to is in allowed values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this structure

```
class Organization
  has_many :clients
end

class Client
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

How can I make sure that when client is assigned to a contact he is a child of a specific organization and not allow a client from another organization to be assigned ?

While searching I did find a `scope` parameter can be added but that seems not to be evaluated when `client_id` is assigned.

**Update**

Here is an example from Rails Docs :

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :year,message: "should happen once per year" }
```

I'm looking for something like "if client is set it must be in Organization.clients"

Comment: If a client can only belong to one organization, how can there be a "client from another organization"? Are you asking how to prevent a client with an existing organization_id from being assigned a different one?

Comment: I would make a custome validation.

Comment: Do you mean when a client is assigned to a contact that the client belongs to a specific organization? I think you need to clarify.

Comment: Does a contact also belong to a certain organization?

Comment: @dewyze you are right. When a client is assigned to a contact it needs to belongs to a specific organization.

Comment: A contact also belongs to a certain organization.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it without custom validation.

Comment: Custom validation are exactly invented or this kind of requirements, where the field can not be validated only by looking at the value alone.

Comment: I've used custom validation for this until now, I was curios to see if there is a way using something like scope. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Contact
  #...
  validate :client_organization

  def client_organization
    unless client.nil?
        unless organization == client.organization
            errors.add(:organization, "can't be different for client.")
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think, based on the original post, the assertion may need to be `if client != nil && organization != client.organization`. It sounds like the client may not be required.

Comment: considering your comment I have updated my answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: I've used custom validation for this until now, I was curios to see if there is a way using something like scope.  I've end up keeping a variation of this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think a custom validation (like @sadaf2605's) is the better way to do things. Don't use a scope for something like this.